# Turn nested list of str into nested list of respective datatypes

Tags: python, list, csv, types

I basically have a nested list which consists of strings - my goal is to turn this list into a list of their respective datatypes. I was successful for strings, dates and floats but my problem is, that the code recognizes integers as floats as well. I tried getting around that with a nested try-except but it doesn't work. Maybe someone finds a solution?

```
from datetime import datetime


l = [['Middle Management', '5', '5584.10', '2019-02-03', '12', '100'],
 ['Lower Management', '2', '3925.52', '2016-04-18', '12', '100'],
 ['Upper Management', '1', '7174.46', '2019-01-02', '10', '200'],
 ['Middle Management', '5', '2921.92', '2018-02-02', '14', '300'],
 ['Middle Management', '7', '2921.92', '2017-09-09', '17', '400'],
 ['Upper Management', '10', '2921.92', '2020-01-01', '11', '500'],
 ['Lower Management', '2', '2921.92', '2019-08-17', '11', '500'],
 ['Middle Management', '5', '2921.92', '2017-11-21', '15', '600'],
 ['Upper Management', '7', '2921.92', '2018-08-18', '18', '700']]

columns = len(l[0]) #the number of columns is given by the number of objects in the header list, at least in a clean CSV
without_header = l[1:]

types_list = []
looping_list = []

for x in range(0, columns):
        looping_list = [item[x] for item in without_header]
        worklist = []
        for b in looping_list:
            try:
                float(b)
                try:
                    b.is_integer() #this is where it fails!
                    worklist.append(int)
                except:
                    worklist.append(float)
            except:
                try:
                    b=datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d")
                    worklist.append(type(b))
                except:
                    worklist.append(type(b))
        types_list.append(worklist)

types_list
```

My output now is:

```
 [float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float],
 [float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float],
 [datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime],
 [float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float],
 [float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float]]
```

But what I'd want is:

`````
[[str, str, str, str, str, str, str, str, str],
 [int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int],
 [float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float],
 [datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime,
  datetime.datetime],
 [int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int],
 [int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int]]
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

One solution which is often used is checking if the number can be cast to an int

Here when the string contains decimals trying to cast to int will raise an error and subsequently add the value to the float array.

Another point of note is that you should add the kind of exception you are expecting rather than catch all the exceptions.
For example when `float(b)` fails it will raise a `ValueError` so capturing this alone is better. Then if something exceptional happens it will be raised to a higher level.

It is also worth noting that if a column is a date but not the date format you have specified that it will be treated as a string. Might be worth a comment about that to save a future debugger time when confronted with such an exception.

```
from datetime import datetime


l = [['Middle Management', '5', '5584.10', '2019-02-03', '12', '100'],
 ['Lower Management', '2', '3925.52', '2016-04-18', '12', '100'],
 ['Upper Management', '1', '7174.46', '2019-01-02', '10', '200'],
 ['Middle Management', '5', '2921.92', '2018-02-02', '14', '300'],
 ['Middle Management', '7', '2921.92', '2017-09-09', '17', '400'],
 ['Upper Management', '10', '2921.92', '2020-01-01', '11', '500'],
 ['Lower Management', '2', '2921.92', '2019-08-17', '11', '500'],
 ['Middle Management', '5', '2921.92', '2017-11-21', '15', '600'],
 ['Upper Management', '7', '2921.92', '2018-08-18', '18', '700']]

columns = len(l[0]) #the number of columns is given by the number of objects in the header list, at least in a clean CSV
without_header = l[1:]

types_list = []
looping_list = []

for x in range(0, columns):
        looping_list = [item[x] for item in without_header]
        worklist = []
        for b in looping_list:
            try:
                float(b)
                try:
                    int(b) #this is where it fails!
                    worklist.append(int)
                except ValueError:
                    worklist.append(float)
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    b=datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d")
                    worklist.append(type(b))
                except ValueError:
                    worklist.append(type(b))
        types_list.append(worklist)

types_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to nested try catch. Just check whether your number is integer or not using this way. It's more natural way to implement it.

```
b = float(b)
if b.is_integer():
  worklist.append(int)
else:
  worklist.append(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `b.is_integer()` to `int(b)` solves the problem. `b.is_integer()` just returns a boolean (True or False).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that can be applied to every value and will produce the detected type:

```
import re, datetime
def get_type(val):
   p = [['\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}(?:\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})*', datetime.datetime], ['^\d+$', int], ['^\d+\.\d+', float]]
   return next((b for a, b in p if re.findall(a, val)), str)

l = [['Middle Management', '5', '5584.10', '2019-02-03', '12', '100'], ['Lower Management', '2', '3925.52', '2016-04-18', '12', '100'], ['Upper Management', '1', '7174.46', '2019-01-02', '10', '200'], ['Middle Management', '5', '2921.92', '2018-02-02', '14', '300'], ['Middle Management', '7', '2921.92', '2017-09-09', '17', '400'], ['Upper Management', '10', '2921.92', '2020-01-01', '11', '500'], ['Lower Management', '2', '2921.92', '2019-08-17', '11', '500'], ['Middle Management', '5', '2921.92', '2017-11-21', '15', '600'], ['Upper Management', '7', '2921.92', '2018-08-18', '18', '700']]
result = [[get_type(b) for b in i] for i in zip(*l)]
```

Output:

```
[[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>], 
 [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>], 
 [<class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>], 
 [<class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>], 
 [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>], 
 [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>]]
```